# Disable validation in nestjs param decorator

Tags: decorator, nestjs

I have a NestJS application that uses passport, and I'd like to add a `@User` param decorator to get the user in the request more easily, similarly to [this example](https://github.com/TrejGun/session-based-authorization-for-nestjs/blob/master/src/common/decorators/user.ts).

However, I also have a global validation pipe that I apply for all incoming requests (bodies, headers, query string), and apply different validation depending on the declared body/query/header type. For some reason, when using the `createParamDecorator()` function, NestJS applies the validator to the req.user object. That is wrong however. The passport user is not part of the request contents, so it shouldn't be validated like that.

Short of copy&pasting `createParamDecorator()`'s source, and stripping out the line that applies the pipes, is there a way to turn off pipes, or at least make my validation pipe ignore non-request related types?

My validation pipe, for reference:

```js
import { ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe<T extends unknown> implements PipeTransform {
  public constructor(private readonly service: ValidationService) {}

  public async transform(value: T, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<T> {
    const className: string | undefined = metadata.metatype && metadata.metatype.name;
    if (className) {
      const errors = await this.service.validate(value, className);
      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        throw new BadRequestException(errors);
      }
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

The one thing I don't want is to modify the above (or the service) to blacklist/whitelist types, as those will be changing rapidly as the application evolves, so it would be big pain point to add them to such lists.

Answer (score 2):

After making [a PR with a change that was supposed to fix this](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/3354), it seems for my particular problem, I could use metadata.type, like so:

```js
import { ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe<T extends unknown> implements PipeTransform {
  public constructor(private readonly service: ValidationService) {}

  public async transform(value: T, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<T> {
    if (metadata.type !== 'custom') {
      const className: string | undefined = metadata.metatype && metadata.metatype.name;
      if (className) {
        const errors = await this.service.validate(value, className);
        if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
          throw new BadRequestException(errors);
        }
      }
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

And the PR in question doesn't even do what I thought it does, so it doesn't really work either.

Comment: For a full code example see https://gist.github.com/josephdpurcell/9af97c36148673de596ecaa7e5eb6a0a. My use case was a bit different, but the principle still applied.